# How can I display a member's photo in a template?

Tags: templates, member-details

I have a template for logged-in users where there's a small sidebar in which I want to display the member's photo.  In the EE documentation, it says to to use the {photo_url} variable, along with {photo_height} and {photo_width}.  Unfortunately, when I put those into my template, EE doesn't even render them.  Am I missing a {exp:} wrapper tag?

Here's what I have now:

```
{exp:member}
 {if photo}
  <div style="background:url({photo_url}); width:141px; height:156px" ></div>
 {if:else}
  <div style="background:url('/images/img1.jpg'); width:141px; height:156px" ></div>
 {/if}
{/exp:member}
```

As it is now, the entire block seems to be erroring out and displaying nothing, however if I remove the `{exp:member}` tags, it always evals to false.  I know I have a photo uploaded for the member that I'm testing with, and if I remove the `{if}` block and just leave in `{photo_url}` it prints the literal value "{photo_url}".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use following code:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
 {if photo}
  <div style="background:url({photo_url}); width:141px; height:156px" ></div>
 {if:else}
  <div style="background:url('/images/img1.jpg'); width:141px; height:156px" ></div>
 {/if}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Take a reference from the doc http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/#custom-profile-data-tag

Comment: That's great, thanks! I assumed that the custom_profile_data was for custom member fields, and not for standard-built in ones... thanks!